# Issues while adding Spring for GraphQL to an existing Spring 3 project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-graphql

I am trying to implement Spring for GraphQL in a existing Spring Boot 3 project. I have followed the steps in the beginners guide, however when I try to run the application, I get several errors. Part of the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Security config:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${password:MISSING")
    private String endpointPassword;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode(endpointPassword))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/graphql", "/graphiql", "/vendor/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().xssProtection().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

[Stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/8NG63FHf)

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace shows that a required class is missing, here a type from Reactor. the `spring-graphql` project has a compile dependency on that, so your application should have it.

Two possibilities:

- your build is explicitly excluding `reactor-core` from its dependencies, you can check that with `mvn dependency:tree`
- the `reactor-core` dependency is corrupted in your local repository, try running `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`.

Comment: The only thing related to reactor I see in the output of the first command is:
```
[INFO] +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.5.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
```

Comment: No luck using the second command either

Comment: you should see reactor-core as a dependency of spring-graphql.